# OBJECT CREATION WITHOUT" NEW" KEYWORD

Tags: java, android

Hi am just wondering what mechanism is this where we get objects which are already created in java or android.For example in android:

```
1.   Toast.makeText(Context context,"String",int duration);
2.   getApplication context();
```

Number one above returns a toast object which we never instantiate ourselves
Number two returns a context object which we never created either .

How does this come to play out,where are the objects created ? Is it something to do with the system creating this objects ? should i concern myself with how they are created or it will be a waste of time and i should rather just use the objects as per the documentation without knowing this.I thought it was a singleton design pattern but the constructor of context is public and context is also abstract so we cannot instantiate it, unless we use a sublcass. Anyone with a sure correct answer please help as this will help me a lot in the long run with my programming.

Comment: every app can have A LOT of objects resulting from help classes that are there for you....

Comment: The Object is created in called method and the reference will be returned

Comment: In case of the first one you can just use "Go to Source" in your IDE and see for yourself.

Comment: That are programming Basics. You should learn this before earning andriod programming

Comment: Methods can return objects.  You should really start with an introductory tutorial on Java, returning something from a method is pretty basic.

Comment: Thanks i know a method can return a primitive type or a reference type i use it all the time but in my case most of the time i use new keyword to get a refernce to an objet.Why cant i do something like this : Toast toast = new Toast();

Comment: Because sometimes it's not that easy. In case of Android, I'm guessing, you have to inflate layout, register this view in WindowManager etc. To make it simpler you just have static method that does it for you.

Comment: Thanks makes sense

Answer (score 2):

No Actually the backend method is creating an object for you.
makeText is a static method of Toast Class which returns a Toast Object.

Suppose you have class named MyClass which has a method of getObject which return an instance of MyClass , so your caller of this method will only have to call the method without any 'new' keyword and you will return him the instance.

Comment: Thanks your answer very simple and informative thanks

Comment: pleasure is on my side :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember Android is largely a framework that takes care of the hard work for you. When you instantiate an activity, you are creating a subclass of a subclass which inherits from the public abstract class Context. So in essence, you are actually just creating a class that has inherited all those methods